# Remove tracking URL parameters from WordLift Faceted Search (Related Articles)

Tags: wordlift

Can we remove the tracking urls parameters ?utm_source=wordlift&utm_medium=wl_faceted&utm_campaign=recommendations used in the related article section?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, WordLift Faceted Search uses a Handlebars template.

The default template looks like this:

```
<script id="faceted-search-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <aside class="wl-cloud-widget-wrapper wl-faceted-wrapper wordlift-cloud-widget wordlift-faceted">
            <h3>{{title}}</h3>
            <nav class="chips">
                {{#each entities}}
                    <span class="chip {{activeClass}}" data-referenced-posts="{{referencedPosts}}"
                          data-id="{{id}}">{{label}}</span>
                {{/each}}
            </nav>
            <section class="cards">
                {{#each posts}}
                    <article class="card" data-post-id="{{ID}}">
                        <a href="{{permalink}}?utm_source=wordlift&utm_medium=wl_faceted&utm_campaign=recommendations">
                            {{#if thumbnail}}
                                <div class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url('{{thumbnail}}');"></div>
                            {{/if}}
                            <div class="card-content">
                                <header class="title">{{post_title}}</header>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </article>
                {{/each}}
            </section>
            <nav class="nav-links">
                <span class="nav-link previous">&#10094;</span>
                <span class="nav-link next">&#10095;</span>
            </nav>
        </aside>
    </script>
```

A developer can create a new template and embed it into the page, then set the `template_id` property of the `wl_faceted` shortcode to the id of the new template.